# Do $2x^2 + 2, −x^2 − x $ ∈ Span{$ x − 1 , x^2 + 2x + 1$}?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

All polynomials are in $\mathbb{R}^3[x]$

> Is $2x^2 + 2, −x^2 − x \in \mathrm{span} \{x − 1 , x^2 + 2x + 1\}$ ?

If so why? How can I answer a question of this sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, we want constants $a,b$ such that
$$2x^2+2=a(x-1)+b(x^2+2x+1)=bx^2+(a+2b)x+(b-a).$$

Evidently then $b=2$, which forces $a=0$. But then $a+2b=4$, and we need a term of $0x$. Thus we cannot find such constant, so $2x^2+2$ is not in the span.

More generally, since powers of $x$ are linearly independent, we can always turn a question of this form into a linear algebra problem. In the above case, we wanted to solve the three equations

\begin{align}
2&=b\\
0&=a+2b\\
2&=b-a
\end{align}
and this is more clearly a linear algebra problem.

Answer (score 0):

$2x^2+2=\lambda(x-1)+\mu(x^2+2x+1)$

$2x^2+2=\mu x^2+x(2\mu+\lambda)+\mu-\lambda$

We must have equal coefficients for the same degree of $x$

$\begin{cases}
\mu=2\\
2\mu+\lambda=0\\
\mu-\lambda=2
\end{cases}
$

$\begin{cases}
\mu=2\\
\lambda=-4\\
\mu-\lambda\ne2
\end{cases}
$

Which shows that $2x^2+2$ is not in the span of $x-1;\;x^2+2x+1$

In a similar way we do for

$-x^2-x=\mu x^2+x(2\mu+\lambda)+\mu-\lambda$

which leads to

$\begin{cases}
\mu=-1\\
2\mu+\lambda=-1\\
\mu-\lambda=0
\end{cases}
$

that is

$\begin{cases}
\mu=-1\\
\lambda=1\\
\mu-\lambda\ne 0
\end{cases}
$

Thus 
$-x^2-x$ doesn't belongs to the span of $x-1;\;x^2+2x+1$ either

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the help. I think you have a mistake here : 2x2+2=μx2+x(2μ−λ)+μ−λ -------------- Its supposed to be 2x2+2=μx2+x(2μ+λ)+μ−λ

Comment: @amd Thank you! I've fixed the errors...